# How can I optimize my network for streaming videos to my PS3?

Tags: home-networking, dd-wrt, ps3-media-server

I'm trying to optimize my network for streaming video to my PS3. 
Currently I get a lot of stutter using PS3 media server.

What can I do to make my network work better for streaming? Should I ditch PS3 media server?

Here is what I currently have.[image]

My videos are stored on the file server.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Edit: All the Asus routers use N wireless.

Comment: I presume getting the PS3 on the RT-N16 via Ethernet is not an option? Because that would solve all your problems ;)

Comment: Doh, yeah I can't do that. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a powerline to connect PS3 to network instead of wireless? Did this with my second one upstairs in bedroom and worked a treat.

Was a while ago but think the below was the product I used:
http://www.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=495008

I ended up with:

Router (downstairs) -> Powerline (downstairs) -> Powerline (upstairs) -> PS3 (upstairs)

Comment: Ah I forgot about this question. Yes your method is exactly what I ended up doing. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

PS3MS works quite well but it would appear from your diagram that the route between the PS3 and the server is via two wireless links and this is probably the biggest part of your problem in terms of the amount of latency and overhead these links are adding to your media streams. Using only the kit in the diagram, your best option would be to get the server onto the same AP as the PS3 using one of its 4 switch ports.

If all the kit needs to be spread out as much as the wireless links imply and direct cabling is not possible, I'd replace the outlying APs with 200Mbit or 1Gbit homeplugs - you'll need 3 in total.

Edit: You could also use just two homeplugs - one to replace the AP on the PS3 and the other connected to the same AP as the servers.

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the wireless. PS3 has awful mediaplayer which is very bad with non-local media.

Or use the PS3 webbrowser with flash player to play the content. It has better buffering.